# mySQL query LEFT OUTER JOIN not showing null

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to output all of the rows in the inventory table with the description from the parts table. Here are the tables:

Inventory Table

[image: Inventory Table]

Parts Table

[image]

What I want is to have all output all of the SKUs from the inventory rows that have a specific orderNumber with the description of the SKU next to it. If the inventory SKU doesn't match a part SKU the description I want to output as NULL.

Here is my existing query:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory LEFT OUTER JOIN parts ON inventory.sku = parts.sku AND parts.description IS NULL WHERE orderID = $orderID
```

please help.

Comment: Based on information provided Id say you have one of two problems: 1) the SKU in one or both of the tables has non display characters causing no records to match.  2) The $orderID being passed in matches no records.  I'd run the query w/o the where clause if you get no records.  If no records return, then you have non-display characters in SKU you need to handle.  maybe trim the records to remove spaces?  if you get records then the $OrderID you're passing in is invalid.  Likley 2nd since a left join should at least return Inventory.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `parts.description IS NULL` condition to your `where` clause, because while joining none of the rows on the right table have `null` on its fields

```
SELECT  *
FROM    inventory
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        parts
ON      inventory.sku = parts.sku
WHERE   orderID = $orderID AND
        parts.description IS NULL
```

**Edit**

Reading your requirements better, seems you want all the rows from the left table, regardless of them being matched or not in the right table. If that's the case, you can get rid of that condition altogether

```
SELECT  *
FROM    inventory
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        parts
ON      inventory.sku = parts.sku
WHERE   orderID = $orderID
```

Comment: That was my first try. With that one all I got was the row with the SKU 11111 because that is the only entry where there is a description for the SKU. Almost like an INNER JOIN.

Comment: 2nd one seems like it should work... if not setup a SQL fiddle w/ example data showing the problem.